# Ionic4 - matInput in MatDialog not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic4

Good evening!

I have an Ionic 4 (5.7.0) Angular app using Angular material (8.1.4), and have an odd case I can't get to the bottom of.

I have a simple dialog service to open generic confirmation/prompt dialogs (`MatDialog`s). The issue is with the prompt dialog; it doesn't always work properly.

```
export class DialogService {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public confirm(text: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      data: text
    });

    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }

  public prompt(data: PromptDialogDto): Observable<string> {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PromptDialogComponent, {
      data
    });

    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

The code for the prompt should be fairly immaterial as it just contains a text box (`matInput`) and two buttons (OK/Cancel). The dialog itself returns as per this:

```
public onOkClick(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close(this.model || '');
}

public onCancelClick(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Currently, I have 3... 'sub-processes'. These are just modals using Ionics `ModalController` to do some actions before returning back. All modals are launched using the same service and all modals are working fine with no errors.

Sub-process 1: Prompt works fine.
Sub-process 2 + 3: Prompt comes up, OK/Cancel buttons work, text input does not.

Can't set focus on the text input at all, it might as well not even exist on the screen for all the interactivity it supplies.

Current usage is approximately:

```
Main app
  --> Sub-process 3
    --> Sub-process 1
    --> Sub-process 2
```

Though there are use cases for something as simple as:

```
Main app
  --> Sub-process 2
```

And still process 2 has the same issue with the prompt dialog, which eliminates one of my theories that it has to do with having too many modals/dialogs being stacked.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Even where to look in particular as to what may be causing this? I've spent enough time attempting to pin it down myself, but with little luck, so hopefully someone here can shed some light.

Thank you.

Edit: TL;DR: The `matInput` text input box on my `MatDialog` prompt dialog is non-functional (can't focus, enter text, anything) in 2 out of 3 usages.

Comment: I didn't get your exact issue. Can you tell me exactly what is the problem with input?

Comment: @Tushar Updated with a TL;DR - the input box (only) doesn't work on my prompt dialog in 2 out of 3 of my cases.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in an answer so as not to leave a question hanging:

There is no answer; I gave up. I switched my `DialogService` from popping open a material dialog window in favour of it popping open an ionic alert instead.

It works, so at this point it's good enough...

Answer (score 0):

[image: uncheck visibility css]

after uncheck visibility css property its working. but affecting whole ionic app visibility.